# Creating a tableview in the form of a 'film strip'

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am developing an RSS-reader-type application. I am toying with the possibility of using a normal TableView application but showing the articles as a film-strip. I am mainly thinking for an iPad application (but possible it works on the smaller iPhone as well).

The idea is to have the cells passing/scrolling across the screen using swipe touches (but horizontal, and not vertical as with the normal TableView). They will be some-kind of miniatures of the full article, and when tapped (or with multi-touch zoom to have better control) can be enlarged to read. Then can then just be be moved on as soon as the user has seen enough of it.

Does anybody know if there is an easy way of accomplishing something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious solution that springs to mind would be to use a UIScrollView, as this will provide the inertial effects, etc. for free - all you'd have to do it populate it with the relevant sub-views. (UITableView's actually use a UIScrollView.)

For more information and sample code, see Apple's [UIScrollView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want horizontal scrolling, take a look at Jeremy Tregunna’s [JScrollingRow](http://codaset.com/jer/jscrollingrow). It’s open source under a public domain licence.